# Java zip file from Netbeans: Error Invalid target release 18

Tags: java

Hi [error invalid target release 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg7qm.png) I am using a netbeans 14 and I exported the zip file and sent it to my instructor. But she keeps having this specific error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of Java did you use to compile your project? What version of Java is your instructor using?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you configured Netbeans to compile based on Java 18 or 19.
And you specified inside the project that the target platform should be Java 18 (you can specify to be compatible to earlier versions, but not the other way round). Very likely you installed Java 18 with Netbeans and just used the default values.

It also seems like your instructor wants to run the code on Java before version 18, so her JVM emits this error.

To solve the situation either downgrade your whole setup or at least configure a compatible value as source/binary format.

I included a screenshot of a Maven project configuration screen.
[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer I forgot to mention that i did this one using java ant as well. Completely new to programming and have no clue if this is one of the reasons as well